# "Fine, then", "That's it, then", Let's go, then" etc, do we need a comma before "then"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

*"Fine, then", "That's it, then", Let's go, then*" etc, do we need a comma before "then"?

Comment: It's a matter of style. You don't *have* to have a comma, but one is commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

**Then**

The word then usually relates to time. It is most commonly used as an adverb.
It has the following meaning:

As a consequence or in that case.

*If that's how you feel, let it go then.*

So there's no need for a comma there.